# Scala method in a class forcing to use Unit (using IntelliJ editor)

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala programming and have a question on an error. I have defined a method inside a class. Below is the code (Private_Rational is the class name)

```
  def + (that: Private_Rational): Private_Rational = {
    new Private_Rational(numer * that.denom + that.numer * denom, denom * that.denom)
    println("I'm in first plus")
  }
```

The above code flashed an error (it forced me to use Unit as the return type), however when I moved the println statement above the new statement, it worked

```
  def + (that: Private_Rational): Private_Rational = {
    println("I'm in first plus") //Moved println here
    new Private_Rational(numer * that.denom + that.numer * denom, denom * that.denom)
  }
```

Can anyone please enlighten on why the compiler didn't like the first one? Appreciate your help.
-Thanks.

Comment: Why would it work in the first case?

Comment: After some research found that Scala functions must return something and it returns the last executed statement. Println is not a returnable statement while the new statement does some computations and returns a value. I think that's the reason.

Comment: There's no "returnable statement". `println` returns `Unit` that's all.

Answer (score 2):

When you wrote the `println()` call at the end, you are executing that function and returning the result of that function. If you check the code of `println()` (hover over the function on Intellij and press CTRL while clicking on the function) you can see this:

```
  def println(): Unit = Console.println()
```

As you can see, the return type of that function is `Unit`. That's why the compiler was complaining about. Your function `+` was supposed to return a `Private_Rational` but you were returning `Unit` instead

Answer (score 1):

The last expression you write in your method will define the return type of the method. Think of it as the method was written as

```scala
  def + (that: Private_Rational): Private_Rational = {
    new Private_Rational(numer * that.denom + that.numer * denom, denom * that.denom)
    return println("I'm in first plus")
  }
```

As Jaime pointed out, the `println()` method return type is `Unit`; that's why the compiler is warning about the return type.

If you switch the statements like you did, you get the expected return type, as the `new Private_Rational(numer * that.denom + that.numer * denom, denom * that.denom)` is now the last statement of that code block.